# Memory-efficient way to create a list of multiple choice quiz answer combinations (with specific conditions)?

Tags: python, memory, python-itertools

I'm trying to create a list of all possible answer combinations to a multiple choice quiz. There are 30 questions in the quiz, with 4 possible answers: `['agree', 'disagree', 'neither', 'skip']`. The output should be a list of sublists with all possible answer combinations to the 30 questions, eg:

```
[['agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree'], ['agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'agree', 'disagree'], etc. ...]
```

There is **one caveat**: `skip` may only be answered to max. 15 questions per quiz.

It appears that `itertools.product` is the most straightforward solution, so I tried:

```
from itertools import product
combinations = product(['agree', 'disagree', 'neither', 'skip'], repeat=30)
```

This is, however, very memory inefficient and constantly crashes my Colab session. Is there a memory-efficient solution that would actually allow me to generate the combinations of quiz answers, and on top of that: how could I implement a max of 15 `skip` answers per quiz?

Comment: Suppose `skip` were not a possibility. Then there would be only 3 choices, and the number of possible answers would be `3**30 = 205,891,132,094,649`. There's not a computer in the world with enough memory to store over 205 trillion answers. And that's just for the answers that contain 0 `skip` responses. You have to rethink things to find a way to proceed that's in the realm of the possible ;-)

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve with the combinations? I think there might be a better way to address that, cause this seems like brute-forcing (4^30 combinations is a lot)

Comment: What are you going to DO with this?  Give us some details, and perhaps we can guide you to something that is practical.

Comment: Haha @TimPeters you're right, I should have done the math prior to jumping to coding. I'm trying to assess the degree to which some parties are more likely to be advised on the main Dutch voting guide [website](https://stemwijzer.nl/). I guess a randomized approach should get me statistically sound results without having to use a supercomputer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using python2 ?

Python3's  itertool.product should not explode your RAM. It should just be a generator.

Your code should work as is, it will however run for quite some time (and as others pointed out 'quite some time' means an amount of time you'd not like to wait with the calculation power of your computer. If I didn't calculate badly, and if your computer can handle 1 million combinations per seconds you had to wait about 36 thousand years)

```
In [21]: 4**30 / 10**6 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365                                                                                         
Out[21]: 36558.901084692
```

Please run following code with python 3:

```
choices = ['agree', 'disagree', 'neither', 'skip']
for i, answer in enumerate(itertools.product(choices, repeat=30)):
    pass
print(i)
```

use your process monitor and you should see, that your process does not require
a lot of memory, but just a lot of CPU.

A brute force solution of having only answers with a max of 15 skip values would be to get all possibilities and reject the ones with more.

another one would be to create first all answers, that contain only
`['agree', 'disagree', 'neither']`,
Then all answers with exactly 1 `'skip'`, with skip at all possible positions
then all answers with exactly 2 `'skip'`s, with skips at all possible indistinguishible positions.
...

Comment: In your code I assume you meant choices not l2.  However, Tim Peters comment above shows this for loop will never finish, so you will never get to print(i).

Comment: Agreed I wouldn't like to wait for the result of the print statement.
4 * * 30 is a rather huge number. Never is a strong word though. ;-)
4 * * 30 is about 10 * * 18

With my computer which handles about 1 million possibilities in a second you just had to wait about seven hundred sixty thousand years

Comment: @DarrylG Thanks I changed `l2` to `choices`

Comment: @KlausF I'm afraid my Colab session won't run for  seven hundred sixty thousand years, but your answer did prevent Colab from crashing!

Comment: Made a mistake forgot a 24 in my calculations.

You just had to wait 36 thousand years. 
I guess this will still be too long even if you have a faster computer than mine

Comment: if you're interested in filtering out answers with more than x "skip" values I could add this to my answer.

Obviously not practical for a multiple choice test with 30 questions but for a test with 15 questions where max 7 questions can be skip it might be something you can wait for